# Where do I put text, instructions, description etc. in an iPhone program?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

When an iPhone program has something like a paragraph or a set of instructions that need to be displayed on screen--basically anything that is longer than two sentences, where does it go?

Should it be stored as an NSLocalizedString (is this stored in the info.plist? I tried searching documentation--I'm a beginner and don't quite understand where that goes)?

Should it simply be hard-coded into the UITextView or UILabel that contains it?

Should it be defined as a constant then referenced in the UITextView/UILabel?

Should it be placed in a .txt file then referenced? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506594/where-to-put-text-files-for-iphone-uitextview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are thinking about localizing the text at all, I'd put it into a strings file:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html

You could also put it into a plist and read the plist file at runtime from the bundle.  Generally try to keep the info.plist clean.

Answer (score 0):

I would put such items in a plist file ad read it in.